# How to fire ajax on address change on Magento2 checkout page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, ajax

I have a custom module. In this I want to fire api via jquery ajax when address is changed. How to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

On payment checkout page I have done this by override (through requirejs-config.js) this file :

```
Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address
```

And can be found here : vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/billing-address.js

Comment: which function needs to be overridden in this file ??

Comment: Please look at the file, you want to fire a call when the address is updated, so I guess you should work on function updateAddress.